# thematic variant: how to distinguish a dislocation and movement?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, variants

For example, the sentence
"I found something interesting in the yard -- a mouse eating cheese."

I am struggling with whether this is a right dislocation or postposing. Or neither of them?

Why I think is dislocation: the element [a mouse eating cheese] is the complement of the pronoun [something].

Comment: Appears that it's neither.

Comment: May I ask how you identify it? If so, then what kind of thematic variant this sentence belongs to?

Comment: What makes you think of dislocation, this phrasing?  Please include the research you have on posing.

Comment: @Tsuki I'm afraid I'm not eminently qualified for the job. By the way, why do you rule out it being an NP in apposition?

Comment: Note that "in the yard" could modify "something interesting" or "found". Depending on how you define terms, that could make a difference.

Comment: @user405662 It seems unlikely because the most natural interpretation of "in the yard" is that it's a complement of the verb *find*, so the 'mouse eating cheese, isn't next to the NP in question (on the most likely reading).

Comment: I'd call it an appositive; if you want to dither about what _in the yard_ is, feel free. It's attached to _find_, but whether the string is steel or rubber is unclear.